# Фрагменты в Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Начал изучать такую тему, как фрагменты. Я хочу добавить в контейнер мой фрагмент, который я предварительно создал.

```
package com.development.kernel.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);

        return view;
    }
}
```

И для него xml разметку.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="#ba33"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

И MainActivity:

```
package com.development.kernel.fragments;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Fragment test = new TestFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.frame_layout, test); //вот здесь возникает ошибка
        ft.commit();


    }
}
```

И разметка main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.development.kernel.fragments.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Я пометил комментарием, где возникает ошибка.

Ошибка - `cannot resolve method add(int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)`

Каким образом можно исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот этот код должен работать. Суть в том что у тебя меденжер не из support библиотеки, а фрагменты из support. Для правильной работы они должны быть одного типа.

```
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(containderId, fragmentInstance)
            .commit();
```